# What's Best Practice For Multiple Types of Users in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm building an application that has multiple types of users. Think: patient and doctor.

A patient has many doctors, and a doctor has many patients.

Initially I was going to put them all under one user, and maybe add a role column, or was considering polymorphic referencing(which I'm not so familiar with yet).

Is it better to do the above, or is it better to simply have them as different Classes. The problem I'm trying to resolve starts with logging in, and then class relations with the join table. For example, How can a User have many Users through Appointments? Is that possible?

What's the best practice for what I'm going for here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If patients have many doctors and doctors have many patients, then you have a many-to-many relationship.  A many-to-many relationship requires a linking table.

Let's call this a "treatments" relationship, (because I don't have a good name for it, it should be a noun) as a doctor treats a patient.  Your migration would be

```
create_table :treatments do |table|
  table.timestamps
  table.integer :doctor_id
  table.integer :patient_id
end
```

Then your associations would have to specify that these ids go to the `users` table.

```
class Treatment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :doctor, class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :patient, class_name: 'User'
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :as_patient_treatments, class_name: 'Treatment', foreign_key: patient_id
  has_many :doctors, through: :as_patient_treatments
  has_many :as_doctor_treatments, class_name: 'Treatment', foreign_key: doctor_id
  has_many :patients, through: :as_doctor_treatments
end
```

You may want to break this out using STI, if you have more behavior which differs between doctor and patient.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
end

class Patient < User
  has_many :as_patient_treatments, class_name: 'Treatment', foreign_key: patient_id
  has_many :doctors, through: :as_patient_treatments
end

class Doctor < User
  has_many :as_doctor_treatments, class_name: 'Treatment', foreign_key: doctor_id
  has_many :patients, through: :as_doctor_treatments
end
```

Another, entirely legitimate approach, especially if you have additional data for patients and doctors, is to have a `doctors`, a `patients`, and a `users` table, instead of STI.  You still need the `treatments` table to link doctors and patients.

The meaning of `User` is an account which can log in.  A doctor and a patient can have a `user_id` to their login account.

```
create_table :users do |table|
  table.timestamps
  table.string :username
  table.string :email
  ...
end

create_table :doctors do |table|
  table.timestamps
  table.bigint :user_id
  table.specialty
  ...
end

create_table :doctors do |table|
  table.timestamps
  table.bigint :user_id
  table.payer
  ...
end

create_table :treatments do |table|
  table.timestamps
  table.bigint :doctor_id
  table.bigint :patient_id
end

class User
  has_one :doctor
  has_one :patient
  ...
end

class Treatment
  belongs_to :doctor
  belongs_to :patient
end

class Doctor
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :treatments
  has_many :patients, through: :treatments

  delegate :username, :email, :to => :user
  ...
end

class Patient
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :treatments
  has_many :doctors, through: :treatments

  delegate :username, :email, :to => :user
  ...
end
```

Comment: Is STI then the appropriate approach if for example a Patient that logs into the website has different data needs than say a doctor, e.g. a Patient has to list his allergies, address, medications, and a Doctor needs different data in his account? They would be accessing the same website, but their logging in should result in a slightly different interaction between them. E.g. A doctor would be able to see his list of patients. A Patient would be able to schedule his appoints.

Comment: If they have different data I would go with seperate tables for doctors, patients, and users.

Comment: 1. Even though they do share some data types? Like name, phone number, etc.?

Also, how would you deal with the issue of logging in?

Comment: Also, can you help me to understand some of the syntax here? ```class_name: 'Treat'``` and ```has_many :as_doctor_treatments```? Shouldn't it instead be ```has_many :treatments``` and ```class_name: 'Treatment'```?

Comment: In the model I am suggesting, put the common attributes, those related to being a user, in the `users` table.  This table is used to log in.  The `doctors` and `patients` table have foreign keys to the `users` table.

Comment: I edited my answer to have `class_name: 'Treatment'` because that was a mistake.  You can name the association whatever you like, and naming it `has_many :treatments` will eliminate the need to specify the class name.  I started that convention from the example with only a `User` class, since the associations would need different names.

Comment: Okay, so to clarify, you're suggesting that best practice is separate tables for everyone, i.e. ```doctors```,```patients```,and ```users```not STI, and linking the first two via foreign key to the ```users`` table. If this is correct, could I please ask you to edit your answer to show me how you would do that? (This is assuming the latter example is STI, and the syntax is different)

Comment: I was thinking in your answer, why doesn't your ```User``` class use ```has_one``` relationships instead of ```has_many```?

Comment: You are correct it should be `has_one`.  I edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can Single table inheritance over here.

```
class User
end

class Patient < User
end

class Doctor < User
end
```

In users table you  will have type column which will decide what type of the user it is.

reference - https://medium.com/@dcordz/single-table-inheritance-using-rails-5-02-6738bdd5101a